# Why ftp_rename throws a php error

Tags: php

Why I get the error `ftp_rename(): Rename folder/my_file: No such file or directory` while the documentation says that it should `Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.` ?

While for other methods (like `ftp_chdir`) it says `Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. If changing directory fails, PHP will also throw a warning.`

I'm I doing something wrong ?

## Edit

Here is my code :

```
    $connection = ftp_connect('host', 21);
    ftp_login($connection, 'username', 'password');
    ftp_pasv($connection, true);

    $result = ftp_rename($connection, 'Out/efffs_v1.0.xml', 'folder/my_file');
    var_dump($result);
```

The output I get :

```
Warning: ftp_rename(): Rename folder/my_file: No such file or directory in MyScript.php on line 96
```

I didn't expect to get this warning.

Comment: Your script probably is getting to `echo $result;`, only $result won't be anything printable if it's boolean false so you'll see no output.  Try `var_dump($result);` for debugging purposes, or `echo $result? "Success": "Failed";` for human-readable output

Comment: You're rigth I'm getting `bool(false)`, But still this does not answer my question, Is getting a warning an expected behavior or are the docs not up to date

Comment: Unfortunately, not all functions that throw errors are properly documented.

Comment: Sounds like out of date/incorrect documentation to me.  I think there's some procedure in place for alerting the PHP team about documentation errors (but I'd have to look up what the process is, so you might as well do that yourself).  In the meantime, while I wouldn't normally recommend doing this, you could for now just use the @ operator to suppress the warning (@ftp_rename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well maybe "folder" in the new folder path which is "folder/my_file" does not exist on your server. That could be why the ftp_rename function fails.

You are right, the documentation for the function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rename.php) does not mention that it gives a warning.

You can submit a bug report for missing documentation on: https://bugs.php.net/report.php?bug_type=Documentation+problem&manpage=function.ftp-rename

You can also leave a note on the documentation page for the function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rename.php

Comment: Thanks. I did report the problem, and it's fixed now https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73958